# Composite Primary Keys of Multiple Tables map to Single Entity Framework POCO Property

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a table with 3 foreign keys to 3 other tables, but the foreign keys are composite, and the first column of the composite foreign keys is the same property for all 3 of the other tables. So I'm working with an sql schema like this....

```
------------------
PLANS
------------------
-EnterpriseID (PK, bigint)
-PlanID (PK, uniqueidentifier)
-CategoryID (FK, uniqueidentifier)
-StatusID (FK, uniqueidentifier)
-LeaderID (FK, uniqueidentifier)

------------------
STATUSES
------------------
-EnterpriseID (PK, bigint)
-StatusID (PK, uniqueidentifier)

-----------------
LEADERS
-----------------
-EnterpriseID (PK, bigint)
-LeaderID (PK, uniqueidentifier)

----------------
CATEGORIES
----------------
-EnterpriseID (PK, bigint)
-CategoryID (PK, uniqueidentifier)
```

So as you can see each tables primary key is composite. Table `Plans` also has a composite *foreign key* to each of the 3 other tables, with `EnterpriseID` being the first column of the composite foreign key for each, and the relevant 2nd column appended.

I'm trying to implement this in Entity Framework Code First with Data Annotations, but I'm not sure how to approach expressing that `EnterpriseID` property in `Plans` is the first column in 3 *different* foreign keys. Here's my model so far...

```
public class ActionPlan
    {
        [Key, Column(Order=0)] 
        [ForeignKey("Category")]
        //[ForeignKey("Status")]
        //[ForeignKey("Lead")]
        public long      EnterpriseID               { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order=1)]
        public Guid      PlanID                  { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Category"), Column(Order=1)]
        public Guid      CategoryID       { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Status"), Column(Order=1)]
        public Guid      StatusID         { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Lead"), Column(Order=1)]
        public Guid      LeadID           { get; set; }

        // NAVIGATION PROPERTIES
        public virtual Status   Status   { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public virtual Lead     Lead     { get; set; }
    }

    public class Status
    {
        [Column(Order=0), Key]
        public long     EnterpriseID                { get; set; }
        [Column(Order=1), Key]
        public Guid     StatusID          { get; set; }
    }

    public class Lead
    {
        [Column(Order=0), Key]
        public long     EnterpriseID          { get; set; }
        [Column(Order=1), Key]
        public Guid     LeadID      { get; set; }
    }

    public class ActionPlanCategory
    {
        [Column(Order=0), Key]
        public long     EnterpriseID                  { get; set; }
        [Column(Order=1), Key]
        public Guid     CategoryID          { get; set; }
    }
```

You can see that I tried to add multiple foreign key attributes to Plan POCOs `EnterpriseID` property, but this isn't allowed. Is this possible to express with attributes? Or do I need to use Fluent API?

Comment: Anything guys? Not possible with attributes? Any Fluent API suggestions?